# Given a pointer to heap allocated memory, how do smart pointer implementations find the appropriate deallocation function for it?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I'm trying to build a custom smart pointer library in C++, for practice sake.

Now, I THOUGHT, that this little project would be easy, just have a list of pointers, another list of the number of references per pointer, and a smart pointer class to encapsulate all this sexy functionality.

Well no, of course it's not that simple, and I soon ran into a problem. Given an arbitrary pointer to heap allocated memory, how do I write my class so it in some way, at some point, finds the correct de-allocation function to use for that pointer (new -> delete, new[] -> delete[], malloc/realloc -> free, etc.)

On top of this, there's also the question of whether or not I can assume that this de-allocation function will only ever take on argument, which feels like an assumption that's not safe to make as god only knows there's probably a two argument de-allocation function hidden in some library I use.

I could solve this by making an abstract class then require users of my library to only use classes derived from it with my smart pointer implementation, but that feels gross, and frankly un-enlightening.

I've been searching for a while and I simply cannot find myself a suitable answer. Thus, I'm here to ask if one of y'all could explain to me how actual smart pointer implementations address this, how do they deal with these issues? Do they even bother?

Comment: Smart pointers in the standard library don't attempt to magically determine the appropriate deallocation function. They require one to be provided as a template argument (`std::unique_ptr`) or at run time e.g. as a constructor parameter (`std::shared_ptr`). The default is `delete` for a pointer to non-array type, or `delete[]` for array (as in `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`). See also: [`std::default_delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete)

Comment: Of course that's how they do it, I'm an idiot. :(

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart pointers in the standard library do not attempt to magically determine the appropriate deallocation function. They expect one to be provided, as a template argument (std::unique_ptr) or at run time e.g. as a constructor argument (std::shared_ptr). If no deleter is thus specified, the default is `delete` for a pointer to non-array type, or `delete[]` for array (as in `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`).

See also: [`std::default_delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete)

Comment: Thx m8, I knew about the deleter thing and the fact that you can specify it manually, but I didn't realize that it wasn't also automatic. This meaning that on the rare occasion that I use smart pointer, I'm pretty sure my implementation resulted in subtle memory leaks, which is both horrifying (them leaks creep up on you) and sorta funny given the purpose of smart pointers, lol.